# _constraints, cannot create refund invoice Odoo v10 community

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10

I have this constraint:

```
_constraints = [
    (_unique_invoice_per_partner,
     _('The Document you have been entering for this Partner has already'
       ' been recorded'),
     ['Control Number (nro_ctrl)', 'Reference (reference)']),
]
```

It is about this field:

```
nro_ctrl = fields.Char(
    string='Control Number', size=32, readonly=True, required=True,
    states={'draft': [('readonly', False)]},
    help="Number used to manage pre-printed invoices, by law you will"
         " need to put here this number to be able to declarate on"
         " Fiscal reports correctly.")
```

This constraint is working if I create an invoice, validate it, and pay it (this field is on `account.invoice` model).

But if I create Refund, then it says that a field is not correctly set:

```
The operation cannot be completed, probably due to the following:
- deletion: you may be trying to delete a record while other records still reference it
- creation/update: a mandatory field is not correctly set

[object with reference: nro_ctrl - nro.ctrl]
```

I have also this method which in theory should allow to "copy" or duplicate an invoice, with that field included:

```
@api.multi
def copy(self, default=None):
    """ Allows you to duplicate a record,
    child_ids, nro_ctrl and reference fields are
    cleaned, because they must be unique
    """
    # NOTE: Use argument name ids instead of id for fix the pylint error
    # W0621 Redefining buil-in 'id'
    #if default is None:
        #default = {}
    default = self._context.copy() #default.copy()
    default.update({
        'nro_ctrl': None, 
        'supplier_invoice_number': None,
        'sin_cred': False,
        # No cleaned in this copy because it is related to the previous
        # document, if previous document says so this too
        'date_document': False,
        'invoice_printer': '',
        'fiscal_printer': '',
        # No cleaned in this copy because it is related to the previous
        # document, if previous document says so this too
        # loc_req':False,
        'z_report': '',
    })
    return super(AccountInvoice, self).copy(default)
```

This is from a migration I'm doing from v8 to v10 community.

I don't know if this `copy` method is even necessary.

How can I create a refund with this constraint in mind? I mean, taking `nro_ctrl` field with it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have create new field **nro_ctrl** and you have write **required=True** in py file.

When you write **required field in py file** then it is **required in Database table**.

In copy method you are updating **'nro_ctrl': None**. Due to that reason you are getting error in creating, because of none value is not allowing in required field.

If **nro_ctrl** field is required in invoice then you must give unique value in copy method of refund.

Comment: Hi, Thank You very much, but I'm not sure I fully understand your point, can You give me an example, please?, do You mean a nro_ctrl value on dict on copy method? But wouldn't that be backfire?

Comment: You have update default.update({'nro_ctrl': None}) , due to that reason you are getting error of required field.

Comment: Okay, but what is the unique value I should use nro_ctrl : self.nro_ctrl for example? Instead of nro_ctrl : None?

Comment: That you need to define based on your requirement may be you can generate  from invoice or write login in copy method..